# Disable <div> on buttonclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, html

I have the following problem.
I have a div (`id = "outline"`) on my page.
Now I would like it to be set `visible="false` when clicked on a button.
The catch is it is way outside the container-div.

[image: screenshot]

I've thought about using a Panel and then the `Panel.FindControl`
but then what happens with the `</div>`?

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client side or the server side?

Comment: I would prefer to do this Code behind.
Also with preferable with c#

Comment: @finxie  - see my response then, you will need to give your div an ID and a `runat=server`.  Once you do this in the code behind just do `outline.visible=false;` in the C# code.

Comment: @dtech - usually means server side...lol @ WT* though

Comment: @JonH deleted the comment since I didn't know the ASP.NET specific term "Code-behind"

Comment: @dtech - no problem just was funny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Server Side**

You dont mention if you want to do this on the server side or via jquery / javascript (client side).

If on the server side set your div to `runat="server"` and in the code behind set the visibility to false.

So your HTML becomes `<div id="outline" runat="server">` and your button click event has a single line:

`outline.Visible=false;`

---

**Client Side**

If you want to do this via jquery (which you should) just give the div an id and use a selector:

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

`$('.target').hide();`

Or via javascript if you aren't using jquery:

`document.getElementById('outline').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

Comment: I changed "outlineDiv" to "outline", which would be the name in code behind.

Comment: Whatever your ID is that is what you would use in the code behind.  So if your html is `<div id="outline" runat="server">` then your code behind becomes `this.outline.visible=false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a onclick to the button with a javascript like this:

```
document.getElementById('outline').style.visibility = "hidden"
```

You can also use "display: none" instead:

```
document.getElementById('outline').style.display = "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

you havent mentioned that do you want to show the container div while disabling the "outline" div??  If so separate them and then try it..is the simple answer.... if you can not separate - group the part you want to hide in to separate div ( which does not incldued "container" div ) and then hide that part only.